# Why does this white noise spectrum have a peak for freq=0?

Tags: python, random, fft, whitenoise

From theory we know that the spectrum of a white noise is constant. S(w)=S0

I have written code where I define a white noise though numpy random. Then I apply the Fast Fourier Transform to it. I would expect some sort of constant function, but I get a peak for w=0. When I apply the fft to a random input, why do I get a peak for freq=0?

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq, ifft
from scipy import  signal
#Define the time limits to create the array
tin=0
tfin=1
#the code works better with power of 2 (64;128;256;512;etc.)
Nt=127
#time span
T=tfin-tin
#time interval
dt=T/Nt
#array of time
t=np.arange(tin,tfin, dt)
#noise
noise=0.3*np.random.rand(Nt)
#array of the function to be transformed
x=noise
#creating the spectrum ordinate array
y=fft(x)
#Obtaining the frequency array correlated to the spectrum
freq=fftfreq(Nt, d=dt)
#Creating the time history from the spectrum
xinv=ifft(y)
#Plotting the spectrum X(w)
#I only want the positive freq values:
freq=freq[:Nt//2]
y=y[0:Nt//2]
#I want freq in rad/s
freq=freq*2*np.pi
#I want the absolute value of the spectrum
y=abs(y)
plt.plot(freq,y , label='Spectrum')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel('w[rad/s]')
plt.ylabel('X(w)')
plt.title('')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: If your noise is zero-mean, then you expect to find a zero a the zero frequency (expected value is zero, actual value will of course vary). You generated noise with a non-zero mean, and so should expect a non-zero zero frequency. The zero frequency is the DC component, the sum of all input values.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, You are right. I thought the random function would automatically generate an array with values between -1 and +1, so with mean equal to zero. Instead it generates values between 0 and +1, with a non zero mean.
Thanks!